# insert into registry batch file

Tags: batch-file

i would like to  add entry to registry with name `LangIDEx`  as `REG_DWORD` type with hexadecimal value `1b`.

I have already:

```
@echo off
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\folder1"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\folder1\folder2"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\folder1\folder2" /v "LangIDEx"/t REG_DWORD "1b"/f /reg:32
pause
```

but it doesnt work properly.

Problem with add parameters

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to put a space before the `/f` and remove the `/reg:32`. If you are trying to access the 32bit part of the registry in a 64bit OS, better use the SysWoW64 binaries.

Comment: well doesn´t work - how can i use SysWoW64 binaries ?

Comment: Sorry, i must be blind. Please, see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\folder1" /f 
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\folder1\folder2" /f 
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\folder1\folder2" /v "LangIDEx" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1b /f 
pause
```

If the intended operations are to be done over the 32bit part of the registry (from a 64bit OS), instead of directly call reg.exe, call `%windir%\syswow64\reg.exe`, the 32bit version of the program.