# Adding a specific key to registry using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way to set add a key to registry, and add a string to key, all in batch file?

I am using a portable version of SublimeText, and I want to have a batch file to set the default ext it opens easily on any windows machine.

I need to add a key called UserChoice, that contains a string value called Progid.

Comment: Yes, type `REG ADD /?` at the command prompt for details of `REG ADD`

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert into registry batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090504/insert-into-registry-batch-file)